# Yii Pjax navbar

Tags: php, yii2, pjax

I'm totally new at Yii framework and I have a little question, I didn't find anything. I use Pjax in main layout (I'm using basic app) so I put

```
Pjax::begin();
```

before $content and then I close Pjax after this. 
So the result is that every link in the page didn't reload the page but links in the navbar reload it. I tried to put the beginning of Pjax before the navbar but it didn't work. Someone get a solution for this. It is weird to have juste a part of the site in Pjax.

Thanks:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, provide the code of your layout. It is hard to say something without it. Basicly, it should be like that:

```
<?php 
use use app\assets\AppAsset;
use yii\widgets\Pjax;
?>
<?php AppAsset::register($this);
<?php $this->beginPage() ?>
<?php $this->beginBody() ?>
<? Pjax::begin(['id' => 'main', 'timeout' => 3000, 'scrollTo' => 0]); ?>
<?= 'Your navbar here' ?>
<?= $content ?>
<? Pjax::end(); ?>
<?php $this->endBody() ?>
<?php $this->endPage() ?>
```